# Open certificate using cmd in c#

Tags: c#

how can I open and view certificate file using the cmd in c#

var cert = new X509Certificate2(productImageByte);

can I use X509Certificate2?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can use [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) or [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) to try out code quickly

Comment: i am trying to open the certification in crypto shell extensions

Answer (score -1):

```
X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate(new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes("Path")));
```

Comment: Please read the help section of this site on how to ask and answer questions.